# CSS issues to be resolved

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu

I have the following issues in [my site](http://crestwoodpainting.com/) regarding CSS,.

There are two sections

A) Menu - desktop

B) Menu - Mobile
 kindly gimme the solution code for this.

> A) Menu - desktop

1. Submenu alignment - under menu item, aligned so no sub menu can slide offscreen (currently slide right, submenu show off screen)

> B) Menu - mobile SubMenu

2. Menu item text should expand sub sub menu - i.e. click "About Us" and sub menu expands (About Us, Reviews, Contact, etc.)
3. Re-clicking menu item ("About Us") collapses submenu. So, Clicking another submenu item ("Services") will collapse the first submenu and expand Services - only one submenu will expand at a time.

Comment: This is not a "do my work for me for free" site.

Comment: I can do that but facing issues in this .. can you solve it for me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Submenu alignment - under menu item, aligned so no sub menu can slide offscreen (currently slide right, submenu show off screen)

`style.css:1145`: - remove padding-left.

```
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:hover > .sub-menu {
    left: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this ... now kindly solve the Mobile menu issues

Comment: @graphypro Please rephrase your mobile issue coz I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: 1) When I click on the "AboutUs" not on the icon, the submenu should be appear

Comment: 2) When I click on the another submenu then the first submenu section should be close by itself i.e. only one submenu should be open at one time .. it should be toggle up and down